# Possible to run a site on Windows/Mac/*nix with USB using XAMPP

Tags: usb, xampp

it seems that it's possible to run a web server on a USB stick using XAMPP, but would this work on Windows, Mac and Linux? I want to run a PHP/MySQL demo site which can be used cross platform. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is a windows compiled application

Unless you use an emulator you might struggle to get it working on linux or mac

Consider a diffrent portable webserver for each OS

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is a cross platform (hence the 'X'), Apache MySQL PHP and Perl application. While the application runs on Windows, Linux and Mac, each installation is a *different set of binary files* for the given platform. While there is a Windows version that can run a from a relative path on a USB stick; no such version exists for Mac or Linux at this time. The installation location for the later operating systems must be on the system's hard drive at /Applications/XAMPP on Mac.